# How does my life total work out with Angel's Grace and Ad Nauseum?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a positive life total and cast [Angel's Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%27s%5d%2b%5bGrace%5d) then [Ad Nauseam](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAd%20Nauseam%5d) and draw my whole deck I know I can't lose the game, but is my life total one or negative a bunch?

Comment: Rulings
9/25/2006 The last sentence applies only if your life total is being reduced by damage. Other effects or costs (such as “lose 1 life” or “pay 1 life”) can reduce your life total below 1 as normal.

Comment: found it. easy enough